# Working with iCloud (manual saving)

Tags: ios, icloud-api

I'm trying to implement my own way for documents- my user creates a document, then he chooses if to upload it to iCloud. Once it's been uploaded to iCloud, I want the document to be available only as read-only- which means I've decided its name, the user written the content, chose to upload, and from now on he can only view the document content and the name or delete the document entirely- but not to modify is content or name.
(The document contains text only).

Is this possible doing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That should be very possible.

You could extend UIDocument for your documents and have the class that manages your documents offer different functionalities that you choose to implement based on if the document's url returns true or not for `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] isUbiquitousItemAtURL:fileURL]`.

Comment: And that will make possible to have the document read-only, and only deletable after sent? Also, it will make it possible to only saving an original document, no autosaving (cause not needed)?

Comment: Actually, do you want your documents only usable from your app?

Comment: Assuming your documents are only for use in your app(s) with UIDocument you can control when things are saved / written / deleted in your class that manages your documents.